# JavaScript: find Object with highest summed values from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array-map

In need the Object with maximum a+b value from myArray

```js
var myArray = [{a:5,b:10},{a:10,b:7},{a:8,b:5}];
```

Right now I have something that returns me the index:

```js
var max = [], maxIndex;
myArray.map(x=>max.push(x.a + x.b))
maxIndex = max.indexOf( Math.max.apply(Math, max))
```

I need something that returns the Object and not its index, so far working with

```js
var maxObject = myArray.map(x=>x.a + x.b).reduce((x,y)=>x>y)
```

returning `false`.

Comment: If you can get the index then you can get the object with `myArray[maxIndex]`

Comment: true, I wanted something more efficient and shorter if possible, not understanding much of the `Array.reduce` yet.

Comment: `myArray.reduce((x,y) => x.a + x.b > y.a + y.b ? x : y)` – you need to return `x` or `y` and not the boolean from the comparison, and if you reduce the array of sums you get the highest sum and not the object.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for map as reduce will itterate over you array.

```
var myArray = [{a:5,b:10},{a:10,b:7},{a:8,b:5}];


var biggestSumObj = myArray.reduce((total,current)=>{
  if((current.a + current.b) > (total.a + total.b)){
    return current;
  }
  return total;
});


console.log(biggestSumObj);
```

fiddle: [return biggest object](https://jsfiddle.net/ut2xqh0m/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` like below

```js
var myArray = [{a:5,b:10},{a:10,b:7},{a:8,b:5}];

const finalResult = myArray.reduce((result, obj) => {
  let sum = obj.a + obj.b;
  if(result.sum < sum) {
    return {sum, obj: {...obj}}
  } 
  return result;
}, {sum: 0, obj: {}})

console.log(finalResult.obj)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like that:

```js
let myArray = [{a:5,b:10},{a:10,b:7},{a:8,b:5}];
let max = myArray[0].a + myArray[0].b;
let maxObject = {...myArray[0]};
    
myArray.map((obj) => {
   if(max < obj.a + obj.b) {
       max = obj.a + obj.b;
       maxObject = {...obj}
    }
});
    
console.log(maxObject); // { a: 10, b: 7 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, after you found the index of the object with the highest summed values
, you simply return the array in that index:

```js
var myArray = [{a:5,b:10},{a:10,b:7},{a:8,b:5}];
var max = [],
  maxIndex;
var result;
myArray.map(x => max.push(x.a + x.b))
maxIndex = max.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, max))
result = myArray[maxIndex];
console.log(result);
```